# Multiple lines on a graph for R

Tags: r, graph

I have this data:

```
 >x<-seq(0,30,by=1) 
 >y<-dbinom(x,30,0.3)
 >plot(x,y)
 >plot(x,y,type="h",lty=1)
 >plot(x,y,type="l",lty=3)
```

and I'm not too sure how to plot it all on one graph. The three different plot() functions are the same line, just one is dotted, one has circles for points and the other has lines up to the points, I just need to combine them. Thanks

Comment: change the second and third `plot`s to `lines`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the functions `?lines` and `?points` to achieve this:

```
plot(x,y,type="h",lty=1)
points(x,y)
lines(x,y,lty=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first graph should be plot() and all others - lines() or points()